# Not able to see TABLE on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have created the tables as below.

```
CREATE TABLE apachelog (
   host STRING, identity STRING, user STRING, time STRING, request STRING, status STRING,
   size STRING, referer STRING, agent STRING)
   ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "input.regex" = "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (-
   |\\[[^\\]]*\\]) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*) (-|[0-9]*)(?: ([^
   \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\"))?", "output.format.string" =
   "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s" )
    STORED AS TEXTFILE
   LOCATION 's3://dinendra80/H4P3';
```

I can see the tables is there and has the correct number of rows.

```
hive> show tables; 
OK 
apachelog 
Time taken: 14.376 seconds
```

I find the warehouse location.

```
hadoop@domU-12-31-39-02-5D-B7:~$ cat hive/conf/hive-default.xml | grep warehouse 
<name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name> 
<value>/mnt/hive_081/warehouse</value> 
<description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
```

Then when I do this, I get an error message.

```
hadoop fs -lsr /mnt/hive_081

lsr: Cannot access /mnt/hive_081: No such file or directory.

Same thing when I look for /mnt/hive_081/warehouse
```

What I am doing wrong? I have done all the setup 3 times from the beginning and I still get the same error.

Comment: How about using this tool?
https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/File+Browser

Answer (score 0):

Because while creating table, you are explicitly specifying table data location to be on '**s3**' file system rather than the one defined in hive-default with keyword **LOCATION**. [...LOCATION 's3://dinendra80/H4P3'..]

This keyword will override default HDFS storage location for tables specified in conf file.

If you remove LOCATION 's3://dinendra80/H4P3', hive will store tables at '/mnt/hive_081/warehouse' and you will be able to play with it from Hadoop cli.